# How to get the max historical price data from yahoo finance?

Tags: python, scrapy, yahoo-finance

I want to get the max  historical price data  with scrapy from yahoo finance.
Here is url of fb(facebook) max historical price data.

```
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/FNMA?period1=221115600&period2=1508472000&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=1qRuQKELxmM
```

In order to write a stock price web crawler ,two problems i can't solve.
1.How to get the argument period1 ?
You can get it by hand in the web page,just to click max.
How to get the argument with python codes?
Different stock has the different period1 value.

[image]

2.How to create the argument crumb=1qRuQKELxmM automatically ,different stocks with different crumb value?
Here is my stock max historical data with scrapy framework.

```
import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    allowed_domains = ["finance.yahoo.com"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.timeout = 10

    def start_requests(self):
        stockName =  get-it and ommit the codes 
        for stock in stockName:
            period1 =  how to fill it
            crumb = how to fill it
            per_stock_max_data = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance\
                  download/"+stock+"?period1="+period1+"&period2=1508472000&\
                  interval=1d&events=history&"+"crumb="crumb
            yield scrapy.Request(per_stock_max_data,callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        content = response.body
        target = response.url
        #do something
```

How to fill the blank above in my web scrawler framework?

Comment: Have you considered using pandas ?

Comment: Wiht pandas , such code is need `start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)`,different stock has different start datetime,the problem remains.

Comment: [This](http://blog.bradlucas.com/posts/2017-06-02-new-yahoo-finance-quote-download-url/) link might be of a help to you as it shows how to get the `crumb` value.

Answer (score 9):

As I understand you want to download all possible data for a specific ticker. So to do this you actually don't need to provide `period1` parameter, if you provide 0 in  the place of `period1` then Yahoo API puts as default the oldest date.

To download quotes using the way you showed in the question we unfortunately have to deal with cookies. I will let myself provide solution without using Scrapy, only ticker itself is required:

```
def get_yahoo_ticker_data(ticker):
    res = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + ticker + '/history')
    yahoo_cookie = res.cookies['B']
    yahoo_crumb = None
    pattern = re.compile('.*"CrumbStore":\{"crumb":"(?P<crumb>[^"]+)"\}')
    for line in res.text.splitlines():
        m = pattern.match(line)
        if m is not None:
            yahoo_crumb = m.groupdict()['crumb']
    cookie_tuple = yahoo_cookie, yahoo_crumb

    current_date = int(time.time())
    url_kwargs = {'symbol': ticker, 'timestamp_end': current_date,
        'crumb': cookie_tuple[1]}
    url_price = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/' \
                '{symbol}?period1=0&period2={timestamp_end}&interval=1d&events=history' \
                '&crumb={crumb}'.format(**url_kwargs)


    response = requests.get(url_price, cookies={'B': cookie_tuple[0]})

    return pd.read_csv(StringIO(response.text), parse_dates=['Date'])
```

If you really need the oldest date then you can use the code above and extract the first date from the response.

```
get_yahoo_ticker_data(ticker='AAPL')
```

I do know that web scraping is not an efficient option but it's the only option we have because Yahoo already decommissioned all APIs. You might find some third party solution but all of them use scraping inside their source code and they add some additional boiler plate code that decreases overall performance.

Answer (score 2):

after installing pandas datareader with:

```
pip install pandas-datareader
```

You can request the stock prices with this code:

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
from datetime import datetime

appl = pdr.get_data_yahoo(symbols='AAPL', start=datetime(2000, 1, 1), end=datetime(2012, 1, 1))
print(appl['Adj Close'])
```

Comment: How to create the `start=datetime` automatically,different stock with different value??

Comment: You put the date into datetime that you want to request and you put the stock code into symbols...

Comment: You can't build a web crawler by hand.

Comment: Maybe I did not get you question then... What do you want to do? Does my code not satisfy your question?

Comment: If the stock set contains  3000 stcoks,how to write `start=datetime` for all of them,one by one with hand?and every stock has the different start datetime value.

Comment: I think it should even work if you use a start date that is before any information for that stock. Give it a try.

Comment: If you use a very early date for all stocks, it should work. Scraping a page to get this sort of data is not efficient. Pandas data reader and @mrCarnivore solve this problem elegantly

Comment: Actually scraping page is the only option to get data. This solution is also using scraping but it's hidden in the source code you better take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/blob/master/pandas_datareader/yahoo/daily.py) to see

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is the whole history you don't really need to compute the max date, use a reasonable old date (in the example below 1900/01/01). For example let's assume you're interested in `FB`'s stock, then this should work

```
import scrapy
import time


class FinanceSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "finance"
    allowed_domains = ["finance.yahoo.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB']

    def parse(self, response):
        crumb = response.css('script').re_first('user":{"crumb":"(.*?)"').decode('unicode_escape')
        url = ("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/FB" +
               "?period1=-2208988800&period2=" + str(int(time.time())) + "&interval=1d&events=history&" +
               "crumb={}".format(crumb))
        return scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_csv)

    def parse_csv(self, response):
        lines = response.body.strip().split('\n')
        print(lines[0])
        print(lines[1])
        print(lines[-1])
```

Comment: I did it, could you please tell me what error message do you receive?, it runs fine with python 2.7 and scrapy 1.3.3

Comment: Could you upload your project's settings? maybe there's a miss configuration.

Comment: have been answered similar in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330327/how-to-get-all-historical-data-from-yahoo-without-specifying-a-start-date-in-pan

Answer (score 0):

1. Both period1 and period2 are "seconds since epoch" values and you can convert between python timestamps and those values using `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(dt)` and `int(dt.timestamp())`. But as others already mentioned, you don't need to specify exact numbers for these parameters, you can use zero for period1 and 2000000000 for period2 for all the stocks.
2. Important that the same "crumb" value is valid for downloading all stocks for some time (around 1 week). So instead of getting a new "crumb" before every download request, you should cache it and update only if you get "Unauthorized" response; your downloads will execute twice faster. The easiest way to get the crumb value is to request Yahoo main page (https://finance.yahoo.com/) and find "user":{"crumb":" substring there.

Answer (score 0):

If you just put a 0 in place of period 1 it should work because the interval will be the beginning of time to the time you just clicked.

The second period you can just put as a really large int such as 1900000000 and it will just take all that occurs until that date.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this thread and wanted to add another option: the Python [yfinance](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/) package. The Ticker API has a history method via which the time period can be specified as `'max'` such that the entirety of the available asset data is returned. Example:

```
import yfinance as yf

spy = yf.Ticker('SPY').history(
    period='max',
    interval='1d'
)
```

The `yfinance` package utilizes the `pandas` package and returns `spy` as a `DataFrame` object as such:

```
                                 Open        High  ...  Stock Splits  Capital Gains
Date                                               ...                             
1993-01-29 00:00:00-05:00   25.236177   25.236177  ...           0.0            0.0
1993-02-01 00:00:00-05:00   25.236163   25.397589  ...           0.0            0.0
1993-02-02 00:00:00-05:00   25.379641   25.469322  ...           0.0            0.0
1993-02-03 00:00:00-05:00   25.487262   25.738368  ...           0.0            0.0
1993-02-04 00:00:00-05:00   25.810116   25.881861  ...           0.0            0.0
...                               ...         ...  ...           ...            ...
2023-01-24 00:00:00-05:00  398.880005  401.149994  ...           0.0            0.0
2023-01-25 00:00:00-05:00  395.950012  400.700012  ...           0.0            0.0
2023-01-26 00:00:00-05:00  403.130005  404.920013  ...           0.0            0.0
2023-01-27 00:00:00-05:00  403.660004  408.160004  ...           0.0            0.0
2023-01-30 00:00:00-05:00  402.799988  405.119995  ...           0.0            0.0

[7555 rows x 8 columns]
```

At the time of writing (1/30/2023) this represents the full, daily, dataset for SPY available via Yahoo Finance. Alternatively, a value of `None` for the `period` argument will result in the same result. Worth noting, omitting a value for the `period` will use the default `"1mo"` value.

**Note**: looking at the source code for Yfinance reveals that a period of "max" or None causes the condition whereby a value of `-2208994789` (1900 in Unix time) is used for the start date.